# Is there a way to load JS and CSS only when necessary?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, single-page-application

We are rewriting a very large legacy Webforms .NET application. Ideally, I would like to have it completely as SPA, based on AngularJS, Bootstrap, and WebAPI. Obviously, the overall look and feel should be consistent across the application.

I have one big concern, however. There are many "rich" controls (calendar, table); not to mention light or shared controls like tooltips or tabs. These control libraries come with their JavaScript and CSS.

The easiest way is to minimize and load all JS and CSS in index.html. But easiest isn't always the best. Even minimized, these libraries come up to a significant size, especially when over half of it is not needed. I realize that Web Components *will* allow such dynamic loading; but until then, should I go for more traditional MVC design, and go to the server for full page reload? Or with the power of today's desktops and browsers I am exaggerating the problem and should just load all the libraries upfront?

Comment: In angularJS there is service called [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) I think using this you can load required js and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angularJS there is service called [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad), I think using this you can load required js and css.

Answer (score 1):

An [$import.js](http://w3core.github.io/import.js/) is a tiny utility, that allows to control js/css/less files loading to the document when only it's necessary.